# Reference for Perturbation theory

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory, eigenfunctions

I need to study the eigenvalues and the eigenfunctions of a perturbated operator knowing the eigenvalues and the eigenfunctions of the initial operator, using the theory of perturbation and writing formulas as asymptotic formulas.

The initial operator is self-adjoint, has compact resolvent and admits simple eigenvalue $\lambda_1\leq \lambda_2\leq \ldots ...$ where $\operatorname{lim}_{n\to+\infty} \lambda_n =+\infty.$

I'm totally new to the theory of perturbation. Could you please give me a reference that explain how should I proceed or eventually if someone could summarize what we do in such case.

Comment: What kind of perturbations do you want to handle? What is your background?

Comment: [Kato](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf).

Comment: @KeithMcClary sorry to ask a stupid question, but since I'm not very familiar with the theory could you please tell me in which chapter should I look because I'm a little lost. I'm looking for something that looks like [this].(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_perturbation)

Comment: You can surely say that there exists a constant $C>0$ (independent of $\varepsilon>0$) such that $$\vert\lambda_j(L_\varepsilon)-\lambda_j(L)\vert \leq C\varepsilon.$$ Would that be enough?

Comment: Actually, I need to know the theory to be able to try to explicit the eigenvalues ​​of the perturbed operator, that's why I was asking about the chapter in Kato.

Comment: My experience is with operators from a Hilbert space to itself.  There are a few things about your statement of the problem I don't understand. As for "explicit", other than in low dimensions (2?), the solutions are iterative or series expansions. The solution in "Eigenvalue perturbation" is first order in the series.

Comment: Can we consider $\Pi$ to be an operator from $L^2(T)$ to $L^2(T)$, i.e., we don't need to know about the Hardy space?

Comment: I would think that $-i\partial_x$ has eigenvalues going to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.